# radio button issue cakephp + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, cakephp

Here is my cakephp code...

```
<?php
$attributes=array('legend'=>false,'separator'=>'<td>'); 
$options=array('N'=>'none','R'=>'read','W'=>'write');
?>

<table>
 <tr class="gray_tab">
    <td class="align-l">English</td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $this->Form->radio('language_english',$options,$attributes); ?>
    </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my javascript

```
var English = 
$("input[type='radio'][name='data[User][language_english]']:checked").val();
alert(English);
```

Now, suppose I choose `R-(read)` from radio button then it is working good first time and i get database updated with that value but after that if i want that radio button updated with `w-(write)` value then my js code returning old value which is set by `cakephp` from database i.e `R-(read).`

i want to get update value of radio button which is different from that of set in database at first time!

Comment: are you using any event...like. onclick.. or onchange or so ???

Comment: yes...

i have 
<?php echo $form->submit('save',array('class'=>'save-btn','onclick'=>'submit();'));

and my js code is inside submit() function...

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this change and let me know if that works:

```
var English =$("input[type='radio']name='data[language_english]']:checked").val();
```